# How do I test the app with Apple Developer Program?

Tags: ios, flutter, testing, deployment, apple-developer

I am working with a team on a mobile application. Everyone would like to use and have this app on their phones. However when I tried to install this app on phones with Xcode I've reached the limit of 5 devices. I wanted to buy an Apple Developer Program account so that I can send this app to other with the help of TestFlight app. Can someone confirm if I understood the information that I found on Apple website correctly:

- I can add testers to the app using the link which will be send to them
- They will be able to download and test the app for 90 days
- They don't have to have Apple Developer Account? (I am not sure about that)
- Since the app will not be published but only uploaded for testing it will not have to go through review process

If someone has better idea how to install application on around 10 devices I will be happy to hear that. If someone has any experience with uploading Flutter app to iOS I will also be happy to hear if there are maybe some tricky parts during this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test users don't need to be part of your developer team, but they must have an Apple ID in order to download the TestFlight App from the App Store.  The email you send the invitation to doesn't have to be their Apple ID.

If the users are not part of your developer program team then your app will need to go through TestFlight review before it is available to them.

The good news is that TestFlight review is not as thorough as release review since Apple understands the app is still under development.  The bad news is that TestFlight review typically takes a few days for a new version vs the typical 12 hour review for an App Store release.

Once you have a version approved for testing, it is best if you can release new TestFlight builds within the same app version. New builds do not require a manual review and can be approved for testing automatically.

If you change the version then another manual review is required.

Comment: In that case, even though they will not have Apple Developer account, can I still add their Apple IDs to my developer team? Because if they are part of my developer team they can have access to the app without Apple's review? And if so, do I do it in Developer account options/ Application options on website or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, you can add their emails to your developer team to remove the need for app review. User admin is now unified between developer.Apple.com and App Store connect.

Answer (score 1):

You understand correctly. Most of the tricky parts handled by XCode usually but if you encounter any issues don't hesitate to ask.